# Recycle bin object that can't be removed after deleting a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am using Oracle version 12c. I have created a trigger that is supposed to create an audit entry thus it's called `before update` (I simplified the following example to make it readable - error stays the same). I am using ant target to `clean db` (first step of the entire `recreate` target). `clean db` step looks like:

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT object_name FROM user_procedures) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP PROCEDURE "' || c.object_name || '"');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

there are two more loops for `user_tables` and `user_views` (skipped for brevity,  call order is `user_tables`, then `user_views` and then `user_procedures`). When I put my trigger in the migration scripts (I'm using flyway):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_car_audit
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON CAR
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CAR (ID, MANUFACTURER, MODEL)
    VALUES (:OLD.ID, :OLD.MANUFACTURER, :OLD.MODEL);
END;
/
```

In the entire `recreate db` ant target, it reaches the point in `clean db` target, where I get:

```
Failed to execute:  BEGIN FOR c IN (SELECT object_name FROM user_procedures) LOOP EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP PROCEDURE "' || c.object_name || '"'); END LOOP; END; 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object BIN$fZDGeHfvC9bhUiQJFawHpg==$0 doesn't exist
```

When I execute: `SELECT * FROM user_procedures`, it gives me:

```
OBJECT_NAME                     PROCEDURE_NAME OBJECT_ID SUBPROGRAM_ID OVERLOAD  OBJECT_TYPE  AGGREGATE  PIPELINED  IMPLTYPEOWNER IMPLTYPENAME PARALLEL INTERFACE  DETERMINISTIC AUTHID   ORIGIN_CON_ID
------------------------------- -------------- --------- ------------- --------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ------------- ------------ -------- ---------- ------------- -------  -------------
BIN$fZDGeHfvC9bhUiQJFawHpg==$0  NULL           120236    1             NULL      TRIGGER      NO         NO         NULL          NULL         NO       NO         NO            DEFINER  0
```

I can get rid of that only by `purge recyclebin;`.

---

1. What might be the reason the `bin*` entry is put in the
   `user_procedures` table ?
2. Is there a way to solve it ? how ?

I have `DROP ANY PROCEDURE` system privilege (I do have other procedures, that are being dropped perfectly fine)

Comment: usually to avoid having bin$ is by using purge command when droping an object. but be aware youll able to flash back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your procedure tries to drop something already dropped. You can recognize that because its name starts with 'BIN$'. That the problem disappears after a purge confirms it.

The solution is to filter on object_name not starting with 'BIN$'

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT object_name FROM user_procedures
              WHERE object_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%' ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP PROCEDURE "' || c.object_name || '"');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: normally I skip this part as I don't want to waste time of the person that helped me. But I was struggling so hard with that and it was so simple. Thus sorry, I have to do that: "Thank you very much, Sir!"